# Parse Semi colon Separated string to a generic list<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics

Sorry about the error , I am updating the question.
I am writing an application that receives input in the following format:

> someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030;

Is there way I can add these values to a generic `LIST<T>`, so that my list contains the following

```
record.someid= 00000-000-0000-000000
record.someotherId =123456789
record.someIdentifier =   3030
```

I am sorry I am newbie at this so asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Split` to get parts of your string which seem to be `key / value pair` combination and add the key and value pair to `Dictionary`.

```
 string str = "someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030";
 string [] arr = str.Split(';');
 Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 for(int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
 {
        string []arrItem = arr[i].Split('=');
        dic.Add(arrItem[0], arrItem[1]);            
 }
```

**Edit** based on comments by OP, to add to custom class list.

```
internal class InputMessage
{
     public string RecordID { get; set;}
     public string Data { get; set;}
}

 string str = "someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030";
    string [] arr = str.Split(';');
List<InputMessage> inputMessages = new List<InputMessage>();
for(int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
       string []arrItem = arr[i].Split('=');
    inputMessages.Add(new InputMessage{ RecordID = arrItem[0], Data = arrItem[1]});         
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var input = "someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030;"
var list = input.Split(';').ToList();
```

After having added to your file's header:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the format is always so strict you can use `string.Split`. You could create a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx):

```
string str = "someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030;";
var idLookup = str.Split(new[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(token => new { 
        keyvalues=token.Split(new[]{'='}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    })
    .ToLookup(x => x.keyvalues.First(), x => x.keyvalues.Last());

// now you can lookup a key to get it's value similar to a Dictionary but with duplicates allowed
string someotherId = idLookup["someotherId"].First();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/EF2BFt)

Comment: This answer is significantly superior to others because:
* Expressed in a single Linq expression
* It trims empty entries
* It provides an indexed look-up

Comment: What it lacks is validation of the format, hence Tim's "If the format is always so strict" - if it isn't followed, i.e. more than one '=' delimiter, then .First / .Last can either return unexpected results

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what `T` is going to be for a `List<T>` in this case, I would put it as a string. If your not sure use `object`.

```
List<object> objList = str.Split(new char[] { ';' }).ToList<object>();
```

Comment: `String.Split` returns an array of String (`String[]`).

Comment: @flem Sorry corrected this, forgot to put my cast in. Just showing the OP that you need to know types or not specify one instead of just saying `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use from following code:

```
        string str = "someId=00000-000-0000-000000;someotherId=123456789;someIdentifier=3030;";

        int Start, End = 0;

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        while (End < (str.Length - 1))
        {
            Start = str.IndexOf('=', End) + 1;
            End = str.IndexOf(';', Start);

            list.Add(str.Substring(Start, End - Start));
        }
```